# click events doesn't work after first click - on browser responsive tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, addeventlistener

click events didn't work after the first click on browser responsive tabs (developer tolls responsive devices) as well as iPad, It perfectly works on normal tabs.

```
$('.element').each(function(index,element){
      element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        //codes
      });  

});
```

Comment: see the `log` on `console`

Comment: check whether the click binding is happening properly

Comment: i checked on console its fine,

Comment: click bind is fine and it's working as excerpted on normal tabs,

Answer (score 0):

'click' event listener not listen on iPad, because iPad's(mobile phones, tablets etc..) make 'touch' events.

see :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

you can use this:

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', _ => console.log('touched'))
```

*(sory for my english)*

Comment: I have issue on ipad an well as browser responsive tabs. Thanks

Comment: if you use 'touchstart' event your issue will be fixed on responsive tabs, iPads etc

Comment: It's working, but I have some confusion, even its iPad click trigger exactly once, after the click didn't trigger

Comment: i'm sorry for incorrect information.. Dont use 'touchstart' event listener. Your code is working fine. 
you shouldn't be having trouble https://codepen.io/yunussahinio/pen/LYELBpG

Comment: I got same issue on https://codepen.io/yunussahinio/pen/LYELBpG, Thanks for your efforts